# $r+s \leq x+y$: How to prove it?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, real-numbers

If the following were true, I could complete an exercise. Is it really true? If it is, has anybody some hint? If it is not, what the counter-example? Need some help! Thanks

**Let $t\in\Bbb{Q}$ and $x,y\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $t\leq x+y$. Then $\exists r,s\in\Bbb{Q}$ such that $r\leq x$, $s\leq y$ and $t=r+s.$**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's false. If (and only if) $x,y \notin \mathbb{Q}$ and $x + y = t$ there won't exist $r,s$ with your properties because $r + s = t = x + y$ together with $r \leq x, s \leq y$ implies $r = x, s = y$.

Comment: I didn't understand, @Arthur. Can you give some counter-example, please? This would prove that the assertion is false.

Comment: $t = 4, x = \pi, y = 4 - \pi$.

Comment: And if I change $\leq$ to $<$? It would be true? @Arthur

Comment: Yes. If $t < x + y$, then just pick an $r \in (t-y,x) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and let $s = t - r$.